# Difference in proving $P \implies (Q \implies R)$ and $(P \land Q) \implies R$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

What is the difference in proving a statement in the form $P \implies (Q \implies R)$ versus $(P \land Q) \implies R$? It seems to me that in both cases one assumes $P$ and $Q$ to be true and tries to deduce $R$. What bothers me is that those aren't equivalent statements, so how could the method of proving them be the same?

Edit: My bad, they're actually equivalent.
$P \implies (Q \implies R) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \;\lor\; (\neg Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (\neg P \;\lor\; \neg Q) \lor R \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \implies R$.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't equivalent statements?

Comment: "those aren't equivalent statements" Yes, they are.

Comment: Are you familiar with natural deduction format proof systems?  If so, then the typical proof tree of $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ would have two ${\rightarrow} I$ as its top-level nodes, while the typical proof tree of $(P \land Q) \rightarrow R$ would have a single ${\rightarrow} I$, followed by two cuts using ${\land} E$ to put $P$ and $Q$ into the context, as the top-level nodes.  Otherwise, the rest of the proof trees could be the same.

Comment: Perhaps you are inadvertently thinking of $(P\implies Q)\implies R$, which is not equivalent to the other two?

Comment: @MJD I was actually thinking of $P \implies (Q \iff R)$ and $(P \land Q) \iff R$, but your example is interesting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statements are logically equivalent. Their proofs are essentially identical. Whether you say that you first assume $P$ and then additionally assume $Q$, or just assume $P$ and $Q$, amounts to the same.